# Sort Algorithm Visualization: How to pull values to animate the canvas, from inside a tight loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, algorithm-animation

I am working on a visualization of different sorting algorithms using the height of different bars with tkinter. I have been able to shuffle the bars and also sort them after some help. The problem I am having now is slowing the sorting of the bars down so it can be seen how each algorithm works. 
Here is what I have so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def swap_two_pos(pos_0, pos_1):
    Bar1x1, _, Bar1x2, _ = canvas.coords(pos_0)
    Bar2x1, _, Bar2x2, _ = canvas.coords(pos_1)
    canvas.move(pos_0, Bar2x1-Bar1x1, 0)
    canvas.move(pos_1, Bar1x2-Bar2x2, 0)


def insertion_sort():
    global barList
    global lengthList

    for i in range(len(lengthList)):
        cursor = lengthList[i]
        cursorBar = barList[i]
        pos = i

        while pos > 0 and lengthList[pos - 1] > cursor:
            lengthList[pos] = lengthList[pos - 1]
            barList[pos], barList[pos - 1] = barList[pos - 1], barList[pos]
            canvas.after(1000,swap_two_pos(barList[pos],barList[pos-1]))
            pos -= 1

        lengthList[pos] = cursor
        barList[pos] = cursorBar
        swap_two_pos(barList[pos],cursorBar)

def shuffle():
    global barList
    global lengthList
    canvas.delete('all')
    xstart = 5
    xend = 15
    barList = []
    lengthList = []

    for x in range(1,60):
        randomY = random.randint(1,390)
        x = canvas.create_rectangle(xstart,randomY,xend,395, fill='red')
        barList.append(x)
        xstart += 10
        xend += 10

    for bar in barList:
        x = canvas.coords(bar)
        length = x[3]-x[1]
        lengthList.append(length)

    for i in range(len(lengthList)-1):
        if lengthList[i] == min(lengthList):
            canvas.itemconfig(barList[i], fill='blue')
        elif lengthList[i] == max(lengthList):
            canvas.itemconfig(barList[i], fill='green')

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Sorting')
window.geometry('600x435')
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width='600', height='400')
canvas.grid(column=0,row=0, columnspan = 50)

insert = tk.Button(window, text='Insertion Sort', command=insertion_sort)
shuf = tk.Button(window, text='Shuffle', command=shuffle)
insert.grid(column=1,row=1)
shuf.grid(column=0, row=1)

shuffle()
window.mainloop()
```

As you can see I tried using the `after()` method in the insertion sort function, but all it does is freeze the window and make it not respond. Without that method, it works fine, just doesn't go at a pace that can be seen.

Comment: hehe, not bad, you are nearly there; the animation you intend requires a pattern that is a little bit tricky to get right the first time; see my answer for details. Your GUI freezing problems happen because you are starting a timer with callbacks (`window.after()`) repeatedly from inside a tight loop. Generally, you want to avoid that, and use `after` to replace a loop, not inside a loop.

Comment: Hi I have a similar problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56368029/how-can-i-animate-bars-on-a-tkinter-canvas-object-to-simulate-the-running-of-m) I'm trying solve and I've been told this should solve my problem, but I'm a noob to python so I was wondering if you could explain to me how the swap_two_pos() method works?... I know what it is supposed to do but I don't understand how it is doing it... thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making use of a generator function (keyword `yield`), you can suspend the execution of the code mid loop to take the time to display the canvas elements that have changed, update calculations, etc., then resume the execution upon calling `next` on the generator repeatedly, until completion of the sort.

I put some comments in the code, but the best way, is probably to stare at it until you convince yourself that it works as it is supposed to. This is a pattern that you need to understand, as it is very useful to construct the sort of animations you want 
to build.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random


def swap_two_pos(pos_0, pos_1):
    Bar1x1, _, Bar1x2, _ = canvas.coords(pos_0)
    Bar2x1, _, Bar2x2, _ = canvas.coords(pos_1)
    canvas.move(pos_0, Bar2x1-Bar1x1, 0)
    canvas.move(pos_1, Bar1x2-Bar2x2, 0)


def _insertion_sort():
    global barList
    global lengthList

    for i in range(len(lengthList)):
        cursor = lengthList[i]
        cursorBar = barList[i]
        pos = i

        while pos > 0 and lengthList[pos - 1] > cursor:
            lengthList[pos] = lengthList[pos - 1]
            barList[pos], barList[pos - 1] = barList[pos - 1], barList[pos]
            swap_two_pos(barList[pos],barList[pos-1])   # <-- updates the display
            yield                                       # <-- suspends the execution
            pos -= 1                                    # <-- execution resumes here when next is called

        lengthList[pos] = cursor
        barList[pos] = cursorBar
        swap_two_pos(barList[pos],cursorBar)


worker = None    # <-- Not a thread in spite of the name.

def insertion_sort():     # <-- commands the start of both the animation, and the sort
    global worker
    worker = _insertion_sort()
    animate()


def animate():      # <-- commands resuming the sort once the display has been updated
                    # controls the pace of the animation
    global worker
    if worker is not None:
        try:
            next(worker)
            window.after(10, animate)    # <-- repeats until the sort is complete,
        except StopIteration:            # when the generator is exhausted
            worker = None
        finally:
            window.after_cancel(animate) # <-- stop the callbacks


def shuffle():
    global barList
    global lengthList
    canvas.delete('all')
    xstart = 5
    xend = 15
    barList = []
    lengthList = []

    for x in range(1, 60):
        randomY = random.randint(1, 390)
        x = canvas.create_rectangle(xstart, randomY, xend, 395, fill='red')
        barList.append(x)
        xstart += 10
        xend += 10

    for bar in barList:
        x = canvas.coords(bar)
        length = x[3] - x[1]
        lengthList.append(length)

    for i in range(len(lengthList)-1):
        if lengthList[i] == min(lengthList):
            canvas.itemconfig(barList[i], fill='blue')
        elif lengthList[i] == max(lengthList):
            canvas.itemconfig(barList[i], fill='green')


window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Sorting')
window.geometry('600x435')
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width='600', height='400')
canvas.grid(column=0,row=0, columnspan = 50)

insert = tk.Button(window, text='Insertion Sort', command=insertion_sort)
shuf = tk.Button(window, text='Shuffle', command=shuffle)
insert.grid(column=1,row=1)
shuf.grid(column=0, row=1)

shuffle()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are a life saver! Thank you so much for your help with this project! What I thought would be a small, fun thing to do wound up being a huge learning experience for me. I obviously still have much to learn but you have been a huge help. Thanks again

Comment: Animating algorithms is a great way to learn, but is is not as simple as it looks and requires some subtle machinery to augment the code of the algorithm itself. There is indeed much to learn implementing this, I am glad I could help you.
Maybe you will like to post a link to your code once you have finished? I'll be happy to have a look at it, and I am sure others too.

Comment: Sure! I'll be sure to let you know when finish/post it.

Answer (score 0):

the time consuming function is "swap_two_pos()" which is catastrophic and you run it every loop, what you should do is finishing your sorting then redraw the bars again,
below is your code modified working without GUI freeze, added a function and removed "swap_two_pos()" func.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random


def insertion_sort():
    global barList
    global lengthList

    for i in range(len(lengthList)):
        cursor = lengthList[i]
        cursorBar = barList[i]
        pos = i

        while pos > 0 and lengthList[pos - 1] > cursor:
            lengthList[pos] = lengthList[pos - 1]
            barList[pos], barList[pos - 1] = barList[pos - 1], barList[pos]
            # canvas.after(1000,swap_two_pos(barList[pos],barList[pos-1]))
            pos -= 1

        lengthList[pos] = cursor
        barList[pos] = cursorBar
    refresh()
        # swap_two_pos(barList[pos],cursorBar)

def refresh():
    canvas.delete('all')
    xstart = 5
    xend = 15

    for i, length in enumerate(lengthList): #range(1,60):
        y = random.randint(1,390)
        x = canvas.create_rectangle(xstart,length,xend,395, fill='red')
        barList.append(x)
        xstart += 10
        xend += 10


def shuffle():
    global barList
    global lengthList
    canvas.delete('all')
    xstart = 5
    xend = 15
    barList = []
    lengthList = []

    for x in range(1,60):
        randomY = random.randint(1,390)
        x = canvas.create_rectangle(xstart,randomY,xend,395, fill='red')
        barList.append(x)
        xstart += 10
        xend += 10

    for bar in barList:
        x = canvas.coords(bar)
        length = x[3]-x[1]
        lengthList.append(length)

    for i in range(len(lengthList)-1):
        if lengthList[i] == min(lengthList):
            canvas.itemconfig(barList[i], fill='blue')
        elif lengthList[i] == max(lengthList):
            canvas.itemconfig(barList[i], fill='green')

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Sorting')
window.geometry('600x435')
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width='600', height='400')
canvas.grid(column=0,row=0, columnspan = 50)

insert = tk.Button(window, text='Insertion Sort', command=insertion_sort)
shuf = tk.Button(window, text='Shuffle', command=shuffle)
insert.grid(column=1,row=1)
shuf.grid(column=0, row=1)

shuffle()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `swap_two_pos` is the key to animate the canvas by updating only the graphic elements that have changed; there is no need to redraw the entire canvas.