# How can I animate 'bars' on a tkinter canvas object to simulate the running of my sorting algorithms?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, algorithm-animation

For a self development project in python I'm trying to create an algorithm animation program but I'm currently stuck on the animation part of my project. So I have gotten the bars to display on the tkinter canvas but I can't figure out how I can get the bars to animate.  PS I am new to python so explanations of code will be helpful or just any explanation of the best way to move forward would be, thanks

```py
from algorithms import *
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

a_list = [] # values of the list I want to sort, starts empty
bar_coords = [] # list of lists of coordinates for each of the bars represented in the canvas

def initialize_list_elements(num_of_elements, up_to):
    list_of_numbers = []
    canvas.delete('all')
    for _ in range(num_of_elements):
        list_of_numbers.append(random.randint(1, up_to))
    return list_of_numbers

def clear_list():
    a_list.clear()
    canvas.delete('all')
    return a_list

def draw():
    x = 0
    a_list = initialize_list_elements(30, 600)
    for value in a_list: # so for each value in our list of values
        x = x + 30 # each
        y = 700 - int(value) # assign a point y
        bars = canvas.create_line((x, 700, x, y), width = 10, fill='black') # then we draw a line using the points (x, 200) and (x, y)
        canvas.create_text(x, y-10, text=str(value))
        bar_coords = canvas.coords(bars)

algorithm_list = ['Binary Search', 'Jump Search', 'Linear Search', 'Bubble Sort', 'Heap Sort', 'Insertion Sort', 'Merge Sort', 'Quick Sort', 'Selection Sort']

window = Tk()
window.title('Algorithm Testbed')
title_frame = Frame(window) # a frame used to display the title of the program
button_frame = Frame(window) # a frame to hold the buttons
canvas_frame = Frame(window) # a frame for the canvas

var = StringVar(button_frame)
var.set(algorithm_list[0])

canvas = Canvas(canvas_frame, width=910, height=700, background='white')

title_label = Label(title_frame, text='Searching & Sorting Algorithm Testbed', font='Helvetica 20 bold')

init_button = Button(button_frame, text='     Initialise     ', width=15, pady=10, command=draw)
start_button = Button(button_frame, text='     Start     ', width=15, pady=10)
pause_button = Button(button_frame, text='     Pause     ', width=15, pady=10)
step_button = Button(button_frame, text='     Step     ', width=15, pady=10)
clear_button = Button(button_frame, text='     Clear     ', width=15, pady=10, command=clear_list)
drop_down_menu = OptionMenu(button_frame, var, *algorithm_list)

# putting the label onto the title_frame
title_label.grid(rowspan=2, column=0)
# putting buttons onto the button_frame
init_button.grid(rowspan=1, column=0, pady=10, padx=5)
start_button.grid(rowspan=1, column=0, pady=10, padx=5)
pause_button.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10, padx=5)
step_button.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=10, padx=5)
clear_button.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=10, padx=5)
drop_down_menu.grid(row=5, column=0, pady=10, padx=5)
# putting canvas onto canvas_frame
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

# putting frames on the window
title_frame.grid(row=0, columnspan=2)
button_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)
canvas_frame.grid(row=1, column=1)
window.mainloop()
```

my code for the algorithms I've left out as there are in a different file and the file is about 200 lines of code didn't want to clog up with too much code.
But where I am drawing the bars on the tkinter canvas is there, again thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You already have the `clear_list` function defined. Can't you just repopulate and call `clear_list` every time, which effectively makes it an animation?

Comment: tkinter canvas does not require you to clear all - you can every iteration, efficiently move the bars that have changed. This question shows you how to equip your code to display the steps of a sorting alogrithm: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55755322/sort-algorithm-visualization-how-to-pull-values-to-animate-the-canvas-from-ins

Comment: thanks didn't see that question, now I just need to understand what is going on